# Redirect all urls to a subfolder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have several old, broken urls that looked like this:
http://www.easyjob.net/partners/whatever.html

I would like to redirect them all to http://www.easyjob.net/partners/general/

The following rule won't work, as the "destination" url will trigger the same rule again, and I'll get a "too many redirects" error.

How can I match any html file inside the /partners/ folder but without matching anything in the /partners/general/ subfolder?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to include your current rule. Did you use the L flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !partners/general/(.*)?
RewriteRule partners/(.*) http://www.easyjob.net/partners/general/ [R=301]
```

You may need to tweak the `RewriteCond` to meet the exact exclusion you're looking for.